# Create blob url download link for a remote file (video, photo, etc)

Tags: javascript, blob

ok let me rephrase my whole question: how do i implement blob url/download links to the remote files located on my server.

---

i've been digging into Google on how to make, or at least convert my plain/regular download link into a blob url. For example, i'd create a download link for a remote video on my server ranging from kb to mb, or even gb in file size but i'd like it downloaded via a blob url. one purpose is to remove/hide the original server path/link.

i know this procedure will be a little bit messy, but i'm up for that. hoping to pick some guides here. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Given the why you want to do it, that is useless.

A blobURI is an URI pointing to the browser's assigned memory on the user's device.

In order to create one, you need to load the remote data on the user's device (in your case it would be in memory).

In order to do it, you would have to allow your user to download the remote data from the original path (URI) to your server.

From this point, this original URI is clearly visible in the Network panel of your user's browser.